# Merging a branch modifies a file that wasn't modified in it

Tags: git

OK, so I have a branch that I want to merge. Out of brevity, let's rename it to BranchName.

```
$ git checkout BranchName
Switched to branch 'BranchName'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'gitlab/BranchName'.
```

Now, I have a specific file. It wasn't modified in this branch, as it's certainly younger than 6 months old.

```
$ git lg **/FileName.cs
* ac3b137db - nat traversal 1.53 (6 months ago) <dangodustj>
* 6f32fc2b8 - nat traversal update, stone pickable, junk (9 months ago) <dangodustj>
* 79b8512c9 - nat (11 months ago) <dangodustj>
```

Now, let's switch back to master.

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'gitlab/master'.
```

This file was modified in master recently:

```
$ git lg **/FileName.cs
* 2150fffea - Remove if (Unity5_3) (5 hours ago) <AlexNik>
* 140c9a2e9 - AddLog (5 hours ago) <AlexNik>
* ac3b137db - nat traversal 1.53 (6 months ago) <dangodustj>
* 6f32fc2b8 - nat traversal update, stone pickable, junk (9 months ago) <dangodustj>
* 79b8512c9 - nat (11 months ago) <dangodustj>
```

So, when I test my merge, I expect no conflicts in this file.

```
$ git merge --no-commit --no-ff BranchName
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
```

However, this is not what actually happens - it will be modified by the merge! As a matter of fact, the changes I did to this file in the master will be reverted.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'gitlab/master'.
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:

        modified:   Assets/NAT Traversal Example/FileName.cs
```

(Edited the merge status to omit all the other modifed files).

What is happening, and why?

Comment: We've tried to track down two similar incidents this week at work and concluded that `git log <filename>` doesn't include all the commits that we expected it to. We merged two branches, one of which had no log whatsoever for the file in question yet we got a merge conflict saying the file had been deleted in that branch. In another incident we got a merge conflict yet again no log for the file in question from one branch. We managed to track down the commits introducing the conflicts in both cases but `git log <filename>` still doesn't include those commits.

Comment: Until we have more information I'm loath to file a bug though.

Comment: I have just tracked it down, will write an answer in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, the reason was in the bad merge commit that happened in `BranchName`. While in `BranchName`, one of the developers decided to merge in the master branch.

```
$ git lg BranchName
*   b3e1488c9 - (HEAD -> BranchName, gitlab/BranchName) Merge branch 'master' into BranchName(7 minutes ago) <Max Yankov>
|\
| *   44b5e21e0 - (gitlab/master, master) Merge branch 'v0.7' (17 minutes ago) <Max Yankov>
| |\
| | * 304622395 - (gitlab/v0.7, v0.7) Changed creature follow constants (77 minutes ago) <Max Yankov>
* | |   ed17d73e3 - MergeWithMaster (29 minutes ago) <StasEremeev>
```

However, while working on the merge commit, he removed all modifications except for the merge conflict resolution:

```
$ git show ed17d73e3
commit ed17d73e32c52b0230010c625c845f50eb47f1e8
Merge: 2e1eec38e 101b691a2
Author: StasEremeev <se.dev@hypetraindigital.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 9 15:35:23 2017 +0300

    MergeWithMaster

diff --cc Assets/Objects/Player/NewWilliam/PlayerACBig.controller
index 91a992a17,d31c43d06..b12458394
--- a/Assets/Objects/Player/NewWilliam/PlayerACBig.controller
+++ b/Assets/Objects/Player/NewWilliam/PlayerACBig.controller
@@@ -115,13 -115,13 +115,13 @@@ AnimatorController
      m_DefaultFloat: 0
      m_DefaultInt: 0
      m_DefaultBool: 0
-     m_Controller: {fileID: 0}
+     m_Controller: {fileID: 9100000}
    - m_Name: Equiped
      m_Type: 1
 -    m_DefaultFloat: 0
 +    m_DefaultFloat: 2
      m_DefaultInt: 0
      m_DefaultBool: 0
-     m_Controller: {fileID: 0}
+     m_Controller: {fileID: 9100000}
    - m_Name: legAngle
      m_Type: 1
      m_DefaultFloat: 0
```

That's the whole commit - all other changes from master were removed from the merge commit. Since this merge commit had all the commits that changed in `FileName` as it's parents, it effectively overrides (and undoes) these changes when you try to merge this branch back into the master.

---

**Update**

I have also witnessed the same behaviour - committing empty merge commit - by hosted Gitlab that we were using:

```
$ git show 428a6d87f
commit 428a6d87fc70bea3a04eff18d7be5665f144102c (HEAD -> master, gitlab/master)
Merge: b7c3bc993 599603a5c
Author: golergka <golergka@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 16 11:23:22 2017 +0000

    Merge branch 'ChangeAttractorRadius' into 'master'

    Change attractor radius

    See merge request hype-train/wild-eight!274
```

This was a merge triggered from Gitlab web interface - and that's the whole merge, without any actual changes being merged.

Comment: Ah, nice catch, I'll have to go back and look at our commits now. Thanks!